# Help with iOS shortcut: translating clipboard text to various languages

Tags: ios, shortcut, shortcuts-app

**What I'm trying to accomplish:**

I made a shortcut for translating text on my clipboard to various specific languages, this is the shortcut:

[image: iOS Shortcut screen 1]
[image: iOS Shortcut screen 2]
[image: iOS Shortcut screen 3]

Also the shortcut can be [downloaded here](https://www.icloud.com/shortcuts/a1da36dc1a5c4e23aaa78af74a40adc1).

As you can see it's very straight forward, I'm only setting a variable “text” from the clipboard, translating it and setting variables for the translation languages (ES, IT, FR, EN, DE), putting all together in text form and showing a preview.

**The problem:**

For some reason, I've been trying to figure it out, when I run the shortcut I get the following error: “Speech translation already ongoing”. Here are a couple of screenshots of the error:

[image: Error screen 1]
[image: Error screen 2]

Some times the error appears after the first translation, some times after the second or third, it appears to be random, I can't figure whats happening. Also, sometimes I've made a duplicate of the shortcut, ran it and it works but after trying a second time it shows the same error.

**What I've tried:**

Some of the things I've tried without success:

1. Using “Nothing” actions between translations.
2. Setting separate variables for the clipboard text each time a new translation starts.
3. Using an action to wait two seconds between translations.

Any ideas? I would really appreciate some help with this.

Comment: i have similar problem. trying to iterate through list with english titles. want to translate them to german. get same error